# UISearchBar frame making x hard to press

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar in my UINavigationBar that also has a button in it. When you click the search field the button gets a bit larger to accommodate text and the search field gets smaller to make space for it.

Although this looks perfect as far as visual UI is concerned the x to clear the search field is almost unclickable.

I am setting the frame by doing

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds;
```

every time the size is meant to change. What should I use instead so that the search bar's x is clickable?

Cheers for any help

Comment: It looks exactly how I want it to, exactly! its just something that should be clickable, the x to clear the field, isn't. And I think its to do with the bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well simple solution, I should be setting the bounds rather than the frame